# Stop cellForRowAtIndexPath when tapping segments

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `segmentedControl` and a `tableView` below it.

`SegmentedControl` has two segments: 'News' and 'Events'.

News and Events are downloaded to `var news = [News]()` in `func getJson(type: Int)`.

For News - `news.type = 1`, for Events `news.type = 2`.

My `getJson` method is:

```
func getJson(type: Int) {
    self.news = [] // empty news array
    if jsonData["type"] == type {
        // save needed news to array
        self.news.append(News(id: jid, title: jtitle, subtitle: jsubtitle, urlstring: jurlstring, image: jimage!))
    }
}
```

So the problem is when I scroll and tap second segment promptly, app crashes:

[image]

Because between `self.news = []` and `self.news.append` in `getJson`, here goes `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

My question is how to stop `cellForRowAtIndexPath` when I tap segments? Thanks.

Comment: What do you return in `numberOfRowsInSection`? and do you call `reloadData` when you switch segments and start to load the data?

Comment: I return `news.count`. I do call. Problem is `tableView` keeps populating cells, but `getjson` does `self.news = []`

Comment: Normally you would load your data into a temporary array and then copy the data to `self.news` once it was loaded and then call reloadData

Comment: yes, it solves the problem, thanks. you can post the answer, i'll accept it

Comment: and one more way, to stop scrolling when i choose the segment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code that is loading data from the network is messing with the array that is driving your tableview then you are going to have problems...and you are.

The typical approach is to load the data into a temporary array in your network load code and then assign this to the actual array (`self.news` in your case) once the load is complete and at that point call `reloadData` on your tableview.

You may also want to consider the user experience while data is being loaded.  I would probably do something like this:

1. When the segment changes, hide the tableview and unhide a UIActivityIndicatorView that is centered on the tableview's location
2. Start loading from the network into a temporary array
3. When the load is complete assign it to `self.news`
4. Reload the table data
5. Hide the UIActivityView and unhide the tableview